# Why does a read-only open of a named pipe block?

Tags: file-io, posix, named-pipes, nonblocking, fifo

I've noticed a couple of oddities when dealing with named pipes (FIFOs) under various flavors of UNIX (Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS X) using Python.  The first, and perhaps most annoying is that attempts to open an empty/idle FIFO read-only will block (unless I use `os.O_NONBLOCK` with the lower level `os.open()` call).  However, if I open it for read/write then I get no blocking.

Examples:

```
f = open('./myfifo', 'r')               # Blocks unless data is already in the pipe
f = os.open('./myfifo', os.O_RDONLY)    # ditto

# Contrast to:
f = open('./myfifo', 'w+')                           # does NOT block
f = os.open('./myfifo', os.O_RDWR)                   # ditto
f = os.open('./myfifo', os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NONBLOCK)   # ditto
```

**Note:** The behavior is NOT Python specific.  Example in Python to make it easier to replicate and understand for a broader audience).

I'm just curious why.  Why does the open call block rather than some subsequent read operation?

Also I've noticed that a non-blocking file descriptor can exhibit two different behaviors in Python.  In the case where I use `os.open()` with the `os.O_NONBLOCK` for the initial opening operation, then an `os.read()` seems to return an empty string if data is not ready on the file descriptor.  However, if I use `fcntl.fcnt(f.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, fcntl.GETFL | os.O_NONBLOCK)` then an `os.read` raises an exception (`errno.EWOULDBLOCK`)

Is there some other flag being set by the normal `open()` that's not set by my `os.open()` example?  How are they different and why?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the Python references and perhaps altering the title of this question. I did happen to run into this while working on a hybrid Python/C++ project, but this is definitely not Python's fault. In my case I was trying to create a fifo in C++ and then later connect to it from Python. I never got that far since the C++ code was hanging.

Comment: To check if a file is fifo (Named pipe) before trying to open it, (eg if you need to exclude it) you can determine such via: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558884/check-if-file-is-a-named-pipe-fifo-in-python

Comment: The third statement is wrong (at least with python3.7): open('myfifo', 'w+') will raise an error: "File is not seekable". Only the last 2 statements are valid.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

That's just the way it's defined. From the Open Group page for the [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/open.html) function

```
O_NONBLOCK

    When opening a FIFO with O_RDONLY or O_WRONLY set: If O_NONBLOCK is
    set:

        An open() for reading only will return without delay. An open()
        for writing only will return an error if no process currently
        has the file open for reading.

    If O_NONBLOCK is clear:

        An open() for reading only will block the calling thread until a
        thread opens the file for writing. An open() for writing only
        will block the calling thread until a thread opens the file for
        reading.
```

Comment: This is precisely the sort of answer I was hoping for (and arguably too lazy to hunt down myself).  It seems like an example of specially overloading the open() semantics with something that's different for FIFOs than for any other sort of file descriptor.  I'm tempted to remove the Python tag from this question as I suspected that it wasn't really Python specific at all; it just happened to be the easiest way for me to provide an example of what I was talking about.

Comment: Yes, Jim Dennis, you weren't the only one thrown for a loop. To me this behavior is not expected at all. I don't see how someone could predict this behavior. Here I was trying to write clean code by only opening the pipe as O_WRONLY only to find out it hangs (and thus I found myself here.) Yes, you should always read documentation, but as Jim pointed out it seems like this changed the semantics of `open` for a specific class of file descriptors. Not very Unix-like at all.