# Python forked processes won't die

Tags: python

I've seen several questions like this one, but after trying various variants of checking if the children are alive and exiting the children processes, I simplified the problem and still it will not work.

Am I wrong in exiting a forked process with sys.exit(0)?
Is there another way to kill it. The thing is, I cannot have the parent kill the processes since it won't know when they're done working.

At first I thought it was because a executed a system command before exiting ([Python run system command and then exit... won't exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807102/python-run-system-command-and-then-exit-wont-exit)), but I've even removed that in the simplified version as given solution didn't work either.

Here's an example:

```
import sys
import os
import time

children = []

for i in range(0,3):    
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == -1:
        continue
    elif pid == 0:
        # Do work...
        print 'Child %d spawned' % os.getpid()
        sys.exit(0)     
    else:
        children.append(pid)

time.sleep(5)
for pid in children:
    proc_path = '/proc/%d' % pid
    if not os.path.exists(proc_path):
        print 'Child %d is dead' % pid
    else:
        print 'Child %d is alive' % pid
```

This prints:

```
Child 27636 spawned
Child 27637 spawned
Child 27638 spawned
Child 27636 is alive
Child 27637 is alive
Child 27638 is alive
```

But child processes should be dead.

What causes these processes to become zombies in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `wait()` for the child-process.

Please add the following lines to get things corrected:

```
import sys
import os
import time

children = []

for i in range(0,3):    
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == -1:
        continue
    elif pid == 0:
        # Do work...
        print 'Child %d spawned' % os.getpid()
        sys.exit(0)     
    else:
        children.append(pid)

time.sleep(5)

# ADD NEXT TWO LINES:
for pid in children:
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)

for pid in children:
    proc_path = '/proc/%d' % pid
    if not os.path.exists(proc_path):
        print 'Child %d is dead' % pid
    else:
        print 'Child %d is alive' % pid
```

The parent must `wait()` for the child. Please see `man 2 wait`for details.

In python you can handle those things with the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thanks. This works, I'll have to add some more logic, but that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

For child to disappear from PID table you need `wait()` on parent's side.

```
n_still_children_alive = len(children)
while n_still_children_alive > 0:
    pid, status = os.wait()
    print "Child %d died and joined" % pid
    n_still_children_alive -= 1
```

If you want to play around with multiprocessing in Python, you're much better of using [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of using `os` module.

Comment: Thanks. I usually do use multiprocessing, which is why I've never had this problem. But for now I'm stuck with python 2.5.