# Check if file is a named pipe (fifo) in python?

Tags: python, pipe

I communicate with a named pipe, but I would like to check if it really is a named pipe BEFORE opening it.

I check in Google but there is nothing, `os.path.isfile()` returns `False`, and I really need to check it.

Comment: A named pipe isn't technically a file so that's why it returns `False`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try:

```
 import stat, os

 stat.S_ISFIFO(os.stat(path).st_mode)
```

[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#S_ISFIFO)