# How do I determine if sys.stdin is redirected from a file vs. piped from another process?

Tags: python, stdin, io-redirection

In a simple Python script intended to be run from the shell, can I reliably determine whether sys.stdin has been redirected from an actual file vs. piped from another process?

I want to change runtime behavior depending on whether stdin is coming from a data file vs. streaming from another process via a pipe.

As expected, **`isatty()`** returns False in both cases.  Here's a quick `isatty()` test:

```
# test.py
import os
import sys
print sys.stdin.isatty()
print os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

Testing:

```
python test.py < file.txt
```

produces:

```
False
False
```

and:

```
ls -al | python test.py
```

produces:

```
False
False
```

Is there a pythonic method of doing this?

Unix/Linux specific is fine, though it would be nice to know if it's possible to do this in a portable manner.

**Edit:** Note in response to commenters: Why do I care?  Well, in my case, I want to deal with time-stamped data that comes in at irregular intervals when piped from another process; when I play back pre-recorded data from a file, I'd like to replay it using a fixed or variable delays.

I agree it's probably advantageous to use a cleaner method (and I can think of several, including an intermediate script to insert delays in the playback stream) but I'm *terminally curious*.

Comment: Why do you care? Isn't the whole point that the two should be indistinguishable? What about `ls -al > file.txt && python test.py < file.txt`?

Comment: I want to reproduce timings between the two environments.  In the immediate case I'm accepting lines (records) of timestamped data in test.py, and would like to process data from the file with similar delays as when I first captured the data.

Comment: Continuing on @Eric `s comment, wouldn't it be better to write your script with two possibilities : either reading from stdin, or from a file given as an argument ?

Comment: @jvivenot: Sure, that's an option, and it's probably a clean way to do it.  But: I'm curious...

Comment: Good comments!  I've updated my Question to clarify my motivations.

Comment: To OP; can you show us the query you used to search SO for similar questions before posting this question? To all people voting up; have you checked for duplicates before voting?

Comment: Related: [Check if file is a named pipe (fifo) in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8558884/95735)

Comment: I see you noticed my sign, WILL GIVE UPVOTES FOR PUNS

Comment: I searched for terms related to stdin, not pipe or fifo -- thus did not find the existing answer.

Comment: @Eric For me, it's because I use a cross platform version of getch, which odesn't seem to work when `python3 palc.py < batchfile` is run. It raises an exception.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for [`stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#module-stat) macros:

```
import os, stat

mode = os.fstat(0).st_mode
if stat.S_ISFIFO(mode):
     print("stdin is piped")
elif stat.S_ISREG(mode):
     print("stdin is redirected")
else:
     print("stdin is terminal")
```

Comment: Excellent!  I tested this and verified that it works as advertised on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Have you checked for duplicates before answering?

Comment: Instead of `os.fstat(0).st_mode` you should use `os.fstat(sys.stdin.fileno()).st_mode`

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim why?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 because `0`  here means file descriptor of _stdin_. Not just a random number. Think about reading this code after 2 years. You'd find this `0` a magic number.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim ah, makes sense. :)