# Check if file is a named pipe (fifo) in C++

Tags: c++, fifo

I have a program reading from a file "foo" using C++ using:

```
pFile = fopen ("foo" , "r");
```

I want it to stop executing the rest of the function if the file is a named pipe. Is there a way to check if the file is a named pipe before opening it?

I found the exact same question using python: 
[Check if file is a named pipe (fifo) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558884/check-if-file-is-a-named-pipe-fifo-in-python) Can I do something similar in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man 2 stat`:

> `int fstat(int filedes, struct stat *buf);`
>
> ...The following POSIX macros are defined to check the file type using the st_mode field:
>
> ```
>          S_ISFIFO(m) FIFO (named pipe)?
> ```

So `struct stat st; ... !fstat(fileno(pFile, &st) && S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode)` should work.

**Edit:** See also SzG's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468960/318716), and Brian's comment to it.

Comment: There is also [`S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62), which is a macro that 
tests for a pipe or FIFO special file.  It is not clear that you can distinguish a pipe from a FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit too late to stop the execution AFTER `fopen()`. It's because the `open()` syscall will block until someone has opened the FIFO for writing. Instead, use the `stat()` syscall (on Unix/Linux) before `fopen()` to find out.

Comment: Using `stat` then `fopen` can lead to a TOCTTOU vulnerability. The best solution if this is a security issue is to `open` non-blocking then `fstat` and `fdopen`.

Comment: I thought a non-blocking `open()` means that the subsequent `read()` calls are non-blocking. But looking up the man pages confirmed that the `open()` itself becomes non-blocking too.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++ there is also [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), it is available since C++17 `#include <experimental/filesystem>`, in C++14 it was [experimental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) `#include <experimental/filesystem>`

So you can you use [is_fifo()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_fifo) now. `filesystem::path` class is constructible from `std::string`, which is construcible from `const char*`, so `filesystem::is_fifo("/path/to/file")` will work as expected. But this version can throw an exception, so `bool is_fifo( const std::filesystem::path& p, std::error_code& ec ) noexcept;` is your choice.

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
  #include <filesystem>
  namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;
#else
  #include <experimental/filesystem>
  namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem;
#endif

bool is_fifo(const char *path)
{
    std::error_code ec;
    bool res = filesystem::is_fifo(path, ec);
    if (ec.value() != 0)
        std::cerr << ec.message() << std::endl;
    return res;
}
```

And don't forget this notice:

> GNU implementation prior to 9.1 requires linking with `-lstdc++fs` and LLVM implementation prior to LLVM 9.0 requires linking with `-lc++fs`.